# Building Pandas Dataframe from nested JSOn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have JSON data in the following format -

```
[
    {
        "score": 0.9228411211686975,
        "keypoints": [
            {
                "score": 0.9997879266738892,
                "part": "nose",
                "position": {
                    "x": 503.1851299157304,
                    "y": 348.069222553839
                }
            },
            {
                "score": 0.9999929070472717,
                "part": "leftEye",
                "position": {
                    "x": 564.1951954588015,
                    "y": 304.60602835323033
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "score": 0.922500729560852,
        "keypoints": [
            {
                "score": 0.9998152256011963,
                "part": "nose",
                "position": {
                    "x": 503.0711610486892,
                    "y": 350.03152797284645
                }
            },
            {
                "score": 0.9999920129776001,
                "part": "leftEye",
                "position": {
                    "x": 564.4444932116105,
                    "y": 305.9835118211611
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to build a pandas DataFrame from it in the following format -

```
         score  keypoints_score         keypoints_position.x         keypoints_position.y
0     0.922841         0.999788                   503.185129                   348.069222
1     0.922841         0.999993                   564.195195                   304.606028
2     0.922500         0.999815                   503.071161                   350.031527
3     0.922500         0.999992                   564.444493                   305.983511
```

I have written the following code -

```
import numpy as np
import json
import os
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

file = open('path_to_a_json_file.json')
data = json.load(file)
df = json_normalize(data, 'keypoints', ['score'], record_prefix='keypoints_')
df1 = df.reindex(columns=['score', 'keypoints_score', 'keypoints_position.x', 'keypoints_position.y'])
print df1
```

This code gives me -

```
         score  keypoints_score         keypoints_position.x         keypoints_position.y
0     0.922841         0.999788                   NaN                   NaN
1     0.922841         0.999993                   NaN                   NaN
2     0.922500         0.999815                   NaN                   NaN
3     0.922500         0.999992                   NaN                   NaN
```

Can someone help point me to the mistake. I think there is some issue with the dataframe `reindex` that I am doing, but can't seem to understnad what is the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my pandas 1.0.1, it only work if `score` is an array or null. You can massage your JSON a bit to make it fit in:

```
# convert score from a scalar to an array of 1
for item in data:
    item['score'] = [item['score']]

# now we can put it into the `meta` argument
json_normalize(data, record_path='keypoints', meta='score', record_prefix='keypoints_')
```

Result:

```
   keypoints_score keypoints_part  keypoints_position.x  keypoints_position.y     score
0         0.999788           nose            503.185130            348.069223  0.922841
1         0.999993        leftEye            564.195195            304.606028  0.922841
2         0.999815           nose            503.071161            350.031528  0.922501
3         0.999992        leftEye            564.444493            305.983512  0.922501
```

Rename, reorder and drop columns as you need.